# Unity saying "the associated script is not valid" for the default scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on a project and I got to the point when I had to write my first script. But when I wrote it, every other script in Unity stopped working.

It says

> "the associated script cannot be loaded, please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script.".

I have NOT edited any of the other scripts, so they should work and when I import them in another project they do work. I can't really start over because I have put weeks worth of work into this and if I start over it won't guarantee that it won't happen again.

here is the script

```c#
#pragma strict

function Start () {
    private var doorIsOpen:boolean=false;
    private var doorTimer:float=0.0;
    private var currentDoor:gameobject;
    public var doorOpenTime:float=3.0;
    public var doorOpenSound:AudioClip;
    public var doorShutSound:AudioClip;

}

function Update () {
    if(dooropen){

        doortimer+=time.deltatime;
        if(doortimer>dooropentime){
        door(doorshutsound,false,"doorshut",currentdoor);
    }
        doortimer = 0.0;

    }


    }


}
function door(aClip : audioclip ,opencheck : boolean, animname : string, thisdoor : gameobject ){
    audio.playoneshot(aclip);
    doorisopen = opencheck;
    thisdoor.transform.parent.animation.play(animname);

}

//function opendoor(){
    //audio.playoneshot(dooropensound)
    //var myoutpost:gameobject = gameobject.find("outpost");
    //myoutpost.animation.play("dooropen");


}
function OnControllerColliderHit(hit:ControllerColliderHit){
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "outpostDoor" && doorisopen = false){


        currentdoor = hit.gameobject;
        door(dooropensound,true,"dooropen",currentdoor);
        dooropen = true;

    }
}

//function shutdoor(){
    //audio.playoneshot(doorshutsound)
    //doorisopen = false;

    //var myoutpost:gameobject = gameobject.find("outpost");
    //myoutpost.animation.play("doorshut");


}

@script requirecomponent(audiosource)
```

Comment: Fix the compile errors.

Comment: Well, as Alberto said, why don't you listen to the error message?

Comment: Did you read what i wrote? i did have not edited the scripts and when i import them in another project they work so there are no script errors..

Comment: Please show us the script you've been working on.

Comment: Did you read what the other commenters wrote? Your existing scripts are fine, but will not work in your project because *all of the scripts* in your project are required to work, else none of them will. Fix the script you are editing and the others will work again.

Comment: i have not even used it in the project yet..

ill try to put the script in the question.

Comment: ok i now understand that i have to first fix the errors in my script before the other scripts can work. so i have put it in the question.
there are 2 errors one is that at (4,9) its expecting } but firnds "private" the other is that at (12,1) it expects EOF but finds } . any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is that the *non-edited* scripts **cannot be compiled** and loaded because of errors in your *new script*. You have to make your new script compiler-friendly.

Comment: Thank you so much i see now what the errors are but i cant seem to fix them. I have put the script in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there will indeed not compile. And given that it will not compile, it will tell you to fix your errors first before you can continue.

So with that determined, let's have a look at your code. Given your function names, I'm assuming you want to extend a MonoBehaviour (that is, make a custom component to attach to a GameObject). In that case you want to write something like:

```js
#pragma strict

class MyCustomComponent extends MonoBehaviour
{

    function Start()
    {
        //Content here
    }   

    function Update()
    {
        //Content here
    }

    //etc.
}
```

This will allow you at add a component named MyCustomComponent to a GameObject in your scene. Secondly, you do not declare your member variables in your `Start()` function. You do that outside of it. So

```js
#pragma strict

class MyCustomComponent extends MonoBehaviour
{
    private var doorIsOpen : boolean=false;
    private var doorTimer : float=0.0;
    private var currentDoor : GameObject; //Note the capitalization
    public var doorOpenTime : float=3.0;
    public var doorOpenSound : AudioClip;
    public var doorShutSound : AudioClip;

    function Start()
    {
        //Content here
    }   

    function Update()
    {
        //Content here
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Those are the main causes of the errors you've listed. Making these corrections should get you on your way. And if anything, look at the many tutorials out there to get an idea about how UnityScript works. And of course, always look at the errors you get. They are usually spot on.